# node js getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js

```
"node": ">=14.5.0"
```

},
"dependencies": {
"@adiwajshing/baileys": "github:WhiskeySockets/Baileys",
"@adiwajshing/keyed-db": "^0.2.4",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.2",
"express-validator": "^6.14.0",
"link-preview-js": "^3.0.4",
"node-cleanup": "^2.1.2",
"pino": "^7.10.0",
"qrcode": "^1.5.3",
"qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
"sharp": "^0.30.7"
},
"devDependencies": {
"eslint": "^8.5.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
"eslint-config-xo": "^0.39.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
"prettier": "^2.5.1"
}
}

returncode: 1 stdout: > start > node . Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chatfastechsecurity.co.in at AxiosError.from (file:///home/gyhvawsr/public_html/chat.fastechsecurity.co.in/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14) at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (file:///home/gyhvawsr/public_html/chat.fastechsecurity.co.in/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:577:25) at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:513:28) at eventHandlers. (/home/gyhvawsr/public_html/chat.fastechsecurity.co.in/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24) at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28) at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9) at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28) at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8) at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)